# How can I reach the safehouse to save the game from the map?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

Everytime I play GTA SA, I get a hard time finding the safe house where the game can be saved. I dont see the floppy disk icon on the map if I am not extremely near. So can anybody suggest me a route so that I can reach the safehouse from anywhere in the city? 
In general I see N,CV,BS,OG icons dominantly.Can anybody suggest how can I reach the safehouse with respect to these icons or any other way so that it can be remembered easily?

Comment: you just drive around and you memorize the city. That's what you should do. And if you are lost you can always check the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BS or big smokes house where most of his missions start is quite near grove st. all you have to do the is go past the ganton gym and you are nearly there, do you know about waypoints? If so you can always put a way point at grove st and follow it.

[image: los santos map]

Grove St is just above the N in Ganton

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use Gta Sa teleport [Link](https://www.thegtaplace.com/downloads/f2049-san-andreas-teleport-30b) to reach to a specific point.A map is display you can teleport to any point from this map .All the location are listed on the map you just need to select and teleport

[image]